# Update repo accessKey for existed application in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Is it possible somehow to update source repo access keys(or retrieve public one) for existed application in AWS Amplify?

## Subject

By some reasons I've revoked all keys from my bitbucket repo, and now my Amplify CI lost access to repo
I don't want to recreate application from scratch and generates new accessKey cause it takes too much efforts

1. I don't see any options and workaround to add/generate new keys and recover access
2. Where are they(keys) stored?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing helped and workaround wasn't found, so I've created new amplify app and on **create-app** new public key was added to the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the access key by going to App settings > General > Re-authenticate app[image]